# Java/AWT/Swing: about validation and sizes

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt

I'm a bit confused at how to manage the layout of my components in Java (I want to do it manually and not handle it by a layout manager). There are these methods in a `Component`:

- `layout`, `doLayout`
- `validate`, `invalidate`, `revalidate`
- `validateTree`, `invalidateTree`
- `setSize`, `setBounds`, `setPreferredSize`
- `getSize`, `getBounds`, `getPreferredSize`
- `paint`, `repaint`, `update`
- `updateUI`

Earlier, I have tried to overload various combinations of the above but I was not quite sure which one to overload and what exactly I have to do inside and what functions I have to call on child components.

---

What I am doing now is:

- Only overload `doLayout` of the above.
- In `doLayout`, for all child components:

  - Call `child.doLayout`.
  - Call `child.setBounds` (sometimes before `child.setBounds`, sometimes after, sometimes both).
- In `doLayout`, because I am doing the layout, I automatically have calculated also its preferred size.
- In `doLayout`, call `this.setPreferredSize`.
- In all constructors, call: `this.setLayout(null)`.
- In some constructors, call: `this.doLayout`. (And if I don't, it doesn't display correctly.)
- When I do some operation where I must redo the layout (e.g. I dynamically have added some textfield in some container and thus I want to resize the container and also all parents accordingly), I call `container.revalidate()`.

---

Remaining problems:

- I think I still haven't really understood what function is calling what, what I have to overload and how to handle.
- In `doLayout`, I call `this.setPreferredSize`. `doLayout` itself often depends on `this.getSize()`. For the parent, often `child.setBounds` depends on `child.getPreferredSize()`. So I have the dilema that in some cases, I first have to call `child.doLayout` and then `child.setBounds` and in some other cases the other way around. And in some cases even more complicated. So it all seems that I have to call `this.setPreferredSize` somewhere else. But where? Because it always has to be updated when the size changes (that is why I had overloaded `setBounds` earlier but that was even more ugly).
- I have everything inside a `JScrollPane` which sets the scrollbars according to `viewportView.getPreferredSize()`. The `revalidate` I am calling in cases where I want to recalculate the layout causes `doLayout` calls which correctly call `setPreferredSize` for all components/containers in the hierarchy. Though, it seems that the `JScrollPane` sets its scrollbar *before* the `doLayout`s got called and thus it is always wrong. How can I fix that?

---

Some further thoughts (please comment on them) about how I maybe could fix the `JScrollPane` problem (haven't really tried because it would require some major rewrites, so I wanted to ask first):

- Remove all `setPreferredSize` calls in `doLayout`.
- Overload `getPreferredSize` and call `doLayout` from there (to get the preferred size).

-- OR --

- Instead of calling `revalidate` when I do something which requires to redo the layout, call `validateTree`.

-- OR --

- Instead of calling `revalidate` when I do something which requires to redo the layout, call all `doLayout` manually and then a `revalidate` on the `JScrollPanel`.

---

And finally, how to I go about the circular dependency of size and preferred size? I.e., I quite often have this case:

- `comp.width` is fixed at the root. I can set the width on the root and recursively go down to all childs and set its width.
- `comp.height` is fixed at the most inner child and depends on its width. So after I have set all widths, I can calculate and sets the heights from the bottom up.

I cannot call `setPreferredSize` before I haven't called `setSize`. And I cannot call `setSize` before I haven't called `setPreferredSize`.

Comment: -1, Why are you reinventing the wheel? "Handling it manually" is in fact writing your own custom layout manager. Why not just use the interface in place so other people will understand your code and will be able to maintain it?

Comment: @camickr: Because I always felt that it doesn't do what I want. Also, my layouting is absolutely trivial; I don't really see why I need a layouter at all. I am quite sure that the actual code to layout my components is much simpler and shorter than to configure and hack any existing layout manager that it works exactly the way I want.

Comment: @Albert, then you don't understand how layout managers work. It is far easier to create custom layout manager with trivial layout logic, then it would ever be to override all those methods you mention above. Until you actually try writing a simple layout manager I don't think you can actually say which is easier. After all your current approach isn't working and that is why you are asking the question. Stick to well known approaches and more people in the forum will be able to help. I have no advice to offer to your problem since I have no idea what your are trying to do.

Comment: Can you describe the layout you're trying to achieve?  I agree with camickr that the way you're attempting it is not good.  If you really can't get any of the existing or 3rd party layout managers to work then I'd at least attempt writing my own first.  I'd even prefer to use a `null` layout and position everything by hand than attempt to simulate a layout manager by trying to override all the required methods.

Comment: @britishmutt: But exactly that is what I am trying to do (use a `null` layout and position everything by hand). I thought it goes that way by overriding some/one of the functions I listed. Actually that was my question. Maybe you misunderstood me.

Comment: @camickr: In any case, no matter if I use a layout manager or not, I want to set the absolute pixel positions by hand (because I am really sure that this is really the most trivial way and also the shortest one - maybe 10 lines of code or so in total). Actually, with my question, I just wanted to ask where I have to put that code and how to do that.

Comment: You put the code in the layout manager. Even if it is hard coded positions and a hard coded preferred size for the panel it belongs in the layout manager.

Comment: @camickr: Where exactly? Read my question again. That is what I am asking. I don't want to overwrite all those methods. I am *asking* what to overwrite and where to put the code.

Comment: @Albert, and you've been given the answer. You create a layout manager and override the methods of the layout manager. There is not need to override any method of any of your components. That is why you use a layout manager, so all the code is in one place and its easy to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid you are in a wrong track.

Use Stewart's answer and set a null layout manager. That allows you to set the position of all components by calling setBounds().

Then, add a listener on the window which is called whenever the window is resized, and recalculate the positions and call setBounds().

This all can be automated if you implement your positioning code as a layoutmanager. (After all, positioning the components at resize == layout management, so believe or not, you *are* developing a layout manager, it is this simple!)

```
public class MyLayout implements LayoutManager,LayoutManager2 {

    @Override
    public void addLayoutComponent(Component comp, Object constraints) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension maximumLayoutSize(Container target) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public float getLayoutAlignmentX(Container target) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public float getLayoutAlignmentY(Container target) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidateLayout(Container target) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
        // Now call setBounds of your components here
    }

}
```

In the layoutContainer method, you can call the setBounds of all the components. This method is called when the window is laid out initially, as well as every time when there is a resize.

Then, when you e.g. put things to a window or to a JPanel, simply setLayoutManager(new MyLayoutManager()) and you're golden.

However, a very crude question still remains. Your layout manager is a separate class, but still it has to access to the components you're created elsewhere in your window code. The brute-force solution is to simply get a reference to all components in the constructor, e.g.:

```
class MyWindow extends JFrame {
   public MyWindow() { 
       JLabel label=new JLabel("Hello");
       JButton button=new JButton("Ok");

       setLayoutManager(new MyLayoutManager(label,button)); // PASS THEM
       add(label);
       add(button);
       pack();
       setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Of course, it is a naive approach, but could work. The proper way for handling this is to implement the addLayoutComponent in your layout manager, which is getting called whenever you add anything to a JFrame (such as when calling add(label)). This way the layout manager is aware of the components in the layout.

Answer (score 3):

All of your issues and questions could be solved if you used LayoutManagers.  You seem to be trying really hard to avoid them but really they are your best ally when it comes to layout out GUI items.

A lot of people try to avoid LayoutManagers at first because of the learning curve.  What I found very useful when I was learning them was the visual guide to layout managers: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html.

My suggestion would be to find a way to get your layout to work with LayoutManagers.  Even you solve some of these issues, making changes or someone else having to read your code is going to be very time consuming. Plus with everything you have to do to get this to work there is a lot of room for bugs due to leaving something out on one component.

Comment: Hm but that all seems very complicated. The absolute positioning code would be trivial. I would not need more than maybe 10 lines in total of code to get what I want, if I only would knew how and where to put that code. (That is what I was asking with my question).

Comment: Depending on your layout needs, it could be less than 10 lines of code.  Plus absolute positioning begins to be a negative when the user changes the size of the frame.

Comment: But I really want to have X/Y fixed (always relative to its container). Only the size should change. But in the way as I described. As a layout manager seem to operate on a single container and not on a hierarchy of containers, I fail to see how they should give me any advantage about my described problem (the circular dependency on sizes).

Comment: You can build a hierarchy of containers each with different layout managers.  There are several very flexible layout managers that either individually or in combination with other managers, can handle just about any setup.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comments, it seems that you just want to do absolute positioning using a null layout.  There's a [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) on it, but the gist is that you set the layout manager to null for your container, and then call setBounds() on each component in that container to set its size and position, like this:

```
JPanel p = new JPanel();
p.setLayout(null);

JButton b = new JButton ("Hit It");
p.add(b);
b.setBounds(new Rectangle(10, 20, 100, 50));
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing now (except that width/height depends on the parent containers width/height) and that works good . The point is when I am resizing, I don't know what function to override of the ones I have listed.

Comment: Also, could you explain, if I want to position `b` at `10, 20, 100, 50`, how any layout manager could make this line more simple: `b.setBounds(new Rectangle(10, 20, 100, 50))`?

Comment: @Albert: for resizing I would add a ComponentListener to the parent container which can then respond to resizing events.

Comment: @Albert: you're right - if you know exactly where you want the component and exactly what size it should be, then there isn't any layout manager that makes specifying exact co-ordinates easier.  But, as you're discovering, when you start to consider resizing behaviour, or anything else that might cause the position or size of a component to change (which is a lot) then you have to manage all that stuff yourself, and it gets difficult.

Comment: @britishmutt: What could cause the position or size of a component to change? I was expecting that without a layout manager, only my own code does that. And that is what I want. I am still wondering though what this `doLayout` is for exactly. (That is what I really asked with my question and what is still unanswered.)

Comment: @Albert: yes, most changes will come from your code, but layout managers still save you from the pain of having to keep all the layout calculations straight when you make such changes.  Other changes can come from outside your code.  Resizing is one example, as are the differences in fonts & rendering schemes between platforms.

Comment: @Albert: as for doLayout(), it basically calls LayoutManager.layoutContainer(), which sets the size and location of each of the container's components according to the layout policy of the particular layout manager in question.