# Java and JScrollPane: where to call setPreferredSize?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I am using a `JScrollPane` and inside `viewportView.doLayout`, I am calling `viewportView.setPreferredSize`. That seems to be wrong though because the scroll bar of the `JScrollPane` is always updated according to the last `setPreferredSize` before `doLayout`. So it seems that in case of a revalidate, the `JScrollPane` is first updating the scroll bar accordingly to the preferred size and then it calls `doLayout`.

Can I change that behavior? Or where should I call `setPreferredSize`? Or where should I put the code which layouts the child components?

---

I figured out one way which works:

Calling both `this.setPreferredSize` and `this.setSize` inside `viewportView.doLayout`.

I leave this question open because I don't really understand why that works (and it doesn't if I remove one of them) and would like to know.

---

Ok, that worked because it generated an endless loop, i.e. it always pushed some revalidation request into the event loop and of course that solves the problem. However, that is not really a solution.

I now have this:

```
// In viewportView of the JScrollPane:
@Override public void doLayout() {
    // ... layout childs ...
    // size.x/size.y being the size I want to have for the viewportView
    if(size.x != getPreferredSize().width || size.y != getPreferredSize().height) {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(size.x, size.y));
        if(getParent() != null) getParent().validate();
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine now.

Still wondering if someone could clarify if this is the right way to go or if not, what it would be.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but afaik calling setSize is what should be done inside the doLayout method. Furthermore the scrollbars reflect the actual size of a component, not it's preferred size although there may be a loose dependency.

Comment: These are the kind of problems you have when you try to reinvent the wheel. You should never have to override doLayout(). Don't you think the designers of Swing thought a great deal about how layout management should work? Albert was advised yesterday in his other posting (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670433/java-awt-swing-about-validation-and-sizes) to use a custom layout manager rather than override all these methods.

Comment: @camickr: Can you explain what you mean with "all these methods"? I am just overriding one single method and just putting there some very trivial code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `JScrollPane`'s content (e.g. a `JPanel`) size set it to the content. If you want `JScrollPane`'s size set it for the `JScrollPane`. No need to call viewPortView's methods.

Comment: But my viewportView is my content. And also, the question was not what I should call but *where* I should do the call.